# Rails gems installed but not functional

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, but I don't know what's wrong with it.  For some reasons, every gem I tried installing recently were successfully installed (as the log reads 'Your bundle is complete!')

But the problem comes when I tried using the gems, they don't seem to be available!

some of the gems I tried using:
- best_in_place
- rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons
and other gems as well.

None of them worked properly, and for instance, the best_in_place gem gives me the following error

> undefined method `best_in_place' for #<#:0x52efc18>

And in gems where I need to specify 'require [gem_name]', I got errors like

> cannot find [gem_name]

This has been very frustrating to me, please help out, and let me know if there is any more information I should provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your source file you need:

```
require 'name_of_gem'
```

for each gem you want to use.

Comment: source file as in the file that uses the method from the gem?

Comment: Yes, and I don't know what gems you are using, but it's likely that "shared" methods would be defined as class methods rather than just defined in the root namespace. So you would likely have to call something like `ClassName.method_to_use`.

Comment: actually, I restarted the server and it works now. Thanks anyway :)